# Parts not moving along armature

Tags: animation

I have tried to animate this model i got.

However there is a problem, some parts of the creature are not moving along it's body. I don't have much experience with blender and i have searched, yet couldnt fix this issue. Could someone try to explain to me what's wrong?

Here is the file for the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WfydBMDL2nNs2JKs1LuquqDOcaexJbgj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mesh is non-manifold, all the hair is separate meshes, it must not help the parenting, you should correct that in *Weight Paint* mode. First select the armature in *Object* mode, shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, in the *Brush* panel disable *Front Faces Only*, in the Falloff panel click on *Projected*:

[image]

[image]

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to select a bone and paint:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot man! Appreciate it.